# How to set seriesData as a percentage using HighCharts dll

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, charts, highcharts

i'm having trouble creating a basic bar HighChart in the way that I need to. I'm creating the chart in C# code and have commented the method throughout to better explain what i'm trying to achieve.

But for the sake of brevity my main issue is that I can't figure out how to format my seriesData as an array of objects that will tell me the Course Name as well as the count of a given Response.

E.g. Completed might contain 'Health & Safety course' and a count of Responses = Completed  (ideally evaluated as a percentage)

I hope my intentions are clear. Thanks in advance.

```
 public DotNet.Highcharts.Highcharts CreateChart(string chartName, string seriesName, DotNet.Highcharts.Enums.ChartTypes chartType)
        {
            string[] courses;  // course objects retrieved from database
            List<Response> completed; // list of response objects where 'State = "Completed"' in database.
            List<Response> started; // list of response objects where 'State = "Completed"' in database.
            List<Response> pending; // list of response objects where 'State = "Pending"' in database.
            List<Target> targets;   // list of targets in database.

            int targetCount = targets.Count();   // i know these lists need to be initialised for this to work but just pretend they are. i'm getting the data just fine using the repository pattern.

            var seriesData = new List<object>();
            object[] completed = new object[0];
            object[] started = new object[0];
            object[] pending = new object[0];
            string[] courseList = courses;

            // What I want here is to create three separate object[](s) like so:
            // object[] Completed = **array of Courses where 'Response = "completed"' including Course Name
            // object[] Started = **array of Courses where 'Response = "started"' including Course Name
            // object[] Pending = **array of Courses where 'Response = "pending"' including Course Name


            // Dummy arrays to test chart and this works. Want to fill these with real data as above though.
            Completed = new object[5] { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 };
            Started = new object[5] { 10, 15, 20, 1, 1 };
            Pending = new object[5] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

            List<DotNet.Highcharts.Options.Series> seriesSet = new List<DotNet.Highcharts.Options.Series>();
            seriesSet.Add(new DotNet.Highcharts.Options.Series
            {
                Type = chartType,
                Name = "Opened",
                Data = new DotNet.Highcharts.Helpers.Data(Completed)
            });
            seriesSet.Add(new DotNet.Highcharts.Options.Series
            {
                Type = chartType,
                Name = "Clicked",
                Data = new DotNet.Highcharts.Helpers.Data(Started)
            });
            seriesSet.Add(new DotNet.Highcharts.Options.Series
            {
                Type = chartType,
                Name = "Data Entry",
                Data = new DotNet.Highcharts.Helpers.Data(Pending)
            });

            DotNet.Highcharts.Highcharts chart = new DotNet.Highcharts.Highcharts(chartName)
                .InitChart(new DotNet.Highcharts.Options.Chart
                {
                    Type = DotNet.Highcharts.Enums.ChartTypes.Bar
                })
                .SetTitle(new DotNet.Highcharts.Options.Title
                {
                    Text = "Departmental Comparison"
                })
                .SetXAxis(new DotNet.Highcharts.Options.XAxis
                {
                    Categories = courseList
                })
                .SetYAxis(new DotNet.Highcharts.Options.YAxis
                {
                    Title = new DotNet.Highcharts.Options.YAxisTitle
                    {
                        Text = "Count"
                    }
                })
                   .SetCredits(new DotNet.Highcharts.Options.Credits
                   {
                       Enabled = false
                   })
                .SetPlotOptions(new DotNet.Highcharts.Options.PlotOptions
                {
                    Column = new DotNet.Highcharts.Options.PlotOptionsColumn
                    {
                        AllowPointSelect = true,
                        Cursor = DotNet.Highcharts.Enums.Cursors.Pointer,
                        Point = new DotNet.Highcharts.Options.PlotOptionsColumnPoint
                        {
                            Events = new DotNet.Highcharts.Options.PlotOptionsColumnPointEvents
                            {

                                Click = "function() { Drillthrough(this.category, this.series.name); }"
                            }
                        }

                    },

                })
                .SetSeries(seriesSet.ToArray());

            return chart;
        }
```

Comment: Highcharts data should have specific format and your problem may be connected with not formatting your code correctly. Here you can find information about how your data should look: http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/series You can set name of your data to Course Name and y value of your data to count of given response.